# Axios and Fetch doesnt sending cookies to api in browset

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, http, axios, fetch

i developed a spring boot api using jwt auth, i got and endpoint
`'http://localhost:8080/api/signin'` and if the login is successfull it returns a JSESSIONID which is a jwtToken. Until there, it's all good, but i can get other methods from API in the browser because the cookies are not being passed in the req body.

The cookie generated by jwt looks like:`JSESSIONID=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTE1Mzk5NSwiZXhwIjoxNjg1MjQwMzk1fQ.9jxHyzDJKVra8IryxbH8se0xSl4_DkapNsKmjRCvlJs_R8M3x3RBMeo-1VPAJv6YSQwC6ukJutRwGEyfeYrGwQ; Path=/; HttpOnly; Expires=Sun, 28 May 2023 02:38:33 GMT;`

For example:
If i do

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/user/admin/all' --header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=mycookie'
```

it goes all good and returns me the json i want, but when i run it on browser, inside my js script from my frontend

```
axios
  .get("http://localhost:8080/user/admin/all", {
    headers: {
      Cookie:
        "JSESSIONID=mycookie",
    },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers);
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Erro:", error);
  });
```

I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/user/admin/all 401
```

The cookie is not being setted. I tried so many things that i almost losing my mind. Do you guys have any idea of what it can be??

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `withCredentials: true`

Comment: I did it and still got the error

Comment: can you post the erro here?